# Gradle doesn't use repositories from "allprojects"

Tags: gradle

If I comment "repositories" on my buildscript, I get an error - even though the repositories are already declared on my "allprojects".

```
    allprojects {
    //...
        buildscript {
                repositories {
                    maven {
                        url "http://www.exemple.com/repositories"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    buildscript {
    //    repositories {
    //        maven {
    //            url "http://www.exemple.com/repositories"
    //        }
    //    }
    dependencies {
            classpath group: 'com.exemple', name: 'exemple', version: '1.2.3'
        }
    }
```

Why does gradle not use the repositories defined on *allprojects* ? The error that I get:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.exemple:exemple:1.2.3 because no repositories are defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

`buildscript` block refers to the classpath for the current script, not a project. You can use it only for a Gradle script. For example:

*example.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      maven {
        url "http://www.example.com/repositories"
      }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.example', name: 'example', version: '1.2.3'
      }
    }
  }
}

// do something, add tasks, etc.
```

*build.gradle*

```
subprojects {
  apply from: 'example.gradle'
}
```